# $('body').addClass('done') does not seem to have any effect

Tags: jquery

I am reading jQuery in Action 2nd edition, really good so far, till I encountered Section: 3.3.2 Moving and copying elements, and reading about copy and move. The example Chap-3 \chapter3\lab.move.and.copy.html) has this statement:

```
$('body').addClass('done');
```

I do not understand what it is doing in this example, as if I comment it out, the example still works just fine.

Also, what are these two statements doing?

```
var operation = $('[name=operations]:checked').val();
targets$[operation](sources$);
```

This part of the book is glossed over, and not written well. This must be expanded with explanation to the example.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`$('body').addClass('done')` is doing exactly what it seems like it's doing from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/): Adding the CSS class "done" to the `body`element`. If you have style rules related to that class, you'll see a difference; if you don't, you won't. Here we have style rules turning text within the body element green if it has that class: http://jsbin.com/ijufis

Re:

```
var operation = $('[name=operations]:checked').val();
targets$[operation](sources$);
```

Not having read the book, I can only tell you what those lines are doing:

1. `$('[name=operations]:checked').val()` is getting the value of a checkbox named `operations`, but only if it's checked (it returns `undefined` otherwise).
2. `targets$[operation](sources$)` is looking up a property on `targets$` based on the value in `operation` and then calling that property's value as a function, passing in the value of the variable `source$` (whatever that is).

Comment: Sorry, I know what .addClass does.  But what is this statement doing in the example?  If I remove it, the example works just fine, with no obvious flaws.

Comment: @KishorPatel: As I said, it's doing exactly what the documentation says it's doing. I can't speak for what the book expects it to do.

Comment: Thank you T.J, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As an example I find it somewhat lacking, but it does have real-world analogs.  I use something like this, but **not** this (see note) to indicate that the page isn't done yet.  It's of small value to the users in many cases, but an easy enough bit of polish to add once it's in there.

The real reason I do it is so that automated tests can navigate the site as fast as possible.  Some test harnesses have a nasty habit of thinking the page is loaded when it's still rendering, and then they'll fail trying to click on something that isn't there yet.  I have the automation folks wait for the 'done' flag before proceeding with the next phase of a test.  Works pretty well, and is a lot faster than "click on link and wait 10 seconds".

**Note Bene:**  Adding a CSS class to the body element from Javascript is considered poor form now.  It pretty much means you're going to get a reflow of the entire page.  Not the wisest choice in general, but doubly damning if you're already trying to compensate for a slow page.